# How to enable SOAP on CentOS

Tags: php, soap, centos, centos7, lamp

We have VPS with CentOS.
I have installed SOAp using the following command:

```sh
$ yum install php-soap
```

Then I went to the `php.ini` file to uncomment the SOAP extension. It was not there, so I added the following line:

```
extension=soap.so
```

Then I restarted the server by running

```sh
$ service httpd restart
```

**But SOAP is still not enabled.**
I get the `Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient'` message.

If I try to install it again, I get following message:

```
Package php-soap-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

I tried to reconfigure PHP with following command as well:

```sh
$ php-config '--disable-fileinfo' '--disable-pdo' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-libxml' '--enable-sockets' '--prefix=/usr/local' '--with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs' '--with-curl=/opt/curlssl/' '--with-imap=/opt/php_with_imap_client/' '--with-imap-ssl=/usr' '--with-kerberos' '--with-libdir=lib64' '--with-libxml-dir=/opt/xml2/' '--with-mysql=/usr' '--with-mysql-sock=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--with-openssl-dir=/usr' '--with-pcre-regex=/opt/pcre' '--with-pic' '--with-zlib' '--with-zlib-dir=/usr' '--enable-soap'
```

Any help?

Comment: I also had to restart my FastCGI service. Because I'm using nginx, the relevant command was `sudo systemctl restart php-fpm`

Answer (score 51):

For my point of view, First thing is to install soap into Centos

```
yum install php-soap
```

Second, see if the soap package exist or not

```
yum search php-soap
```

third, thus you must see some result of soap package you installed, now type a command in your terminal in the root folder for searching the location of soap for specific path

```
find -name soap.so
```

fourth, you will see the exact path where its installed/located, simply copy the path and find the php.ini to add the extension path,

usually the path of php.ini file in centos 6 is in

```
/etc/php.ini
```

fifth, add a line of code from below into php.ini file

```
extension='/usr/lib/php/modules/soap.so'
```

and then save the file and exit.

sixth run apache restart command in Centos. I think there is two command that can restart your apache ( whichever is easier for you )

```
service httpd restart
```

OR

```
apachectl restart
```

Lastly, check phpinfo() output in browser, you should see SOAP section where SOAP CLIENT, SOAP SERVER etc are listed and shown Enabled.

Comment: In recent versions of CentOS, the PHP config for extensions is in /etc/php.d, with a separate .ini file for each extension. But in my case, after I ran yum install php-soap, all I had to do was restart Apache; the soap.ini file was already there.

Comment: @Anil after run this command find -name soap.so in root folder i see this is soap path ./usr/lib64/php/modules/soap.so i set this line in my extension='./usr/lib64/php/modules/soap.so' /etc/php.ini file and restart httpd services in cent os 6. but still it couldn't enable soap service. any idea?

Comment: @mattBrowne for me restarting apache didn't help I had to restart php-fpm service.

Answer (score 13):

On CentOS 7, the following works:

```
yum install php-soap
```

This will automatically create a soap.ini under /etc/php.d.

The extension itself for me lives in /usr/lib64/php/modules. You can confirm your extension directory by doing:

```
php -i | grep extension_dir
```

Once this has been installed, you can simply restart Apache using the new service manager like so:

```
systemctl restart httpd
```

Thanks to Matt Browne for the info about /etc/php.d.

Comment: I tried this. But I have an error trying to install php-soap so I searched and found this:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23919341/error-php55w-common-conflicts-with-php-common-on-centos-6-5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23919341/error-php55w-common-conflicts-with-php-common-on-centos-6-5)


long story short. This solved my problem:
`yum install php55w-soap`

Comment: For a 2018 update - I had an `Error: php56w-common conflicts with ...` and so just modified the install command which @GaboLato mentioned with the number from my error: `yum install php56w-soap` and everything worked fine!

Answer (score 9):

I installed php-soap to CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core) using following way.

1) yum install php-soap

```
================================================================================
 Package              Arch           Version                 Repository    Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 php-soap             x86_64         5.4.16-36.el7_1         base         157 k
Updating for dependencies:
 php                  x86_64         5.4.16-36.el7_1         base         1.4 M
 php-cli              x86_64         5.4.16-36.el7_1         base         2.7 M
 php-common           x86_64         5.4.16-36.el7_1         base         563 k
 php-devel            x86_64         5.4.16-36.el7_1         base         600 k
 php-gd               x86_64         5.4.16-36.el7_1         base         126 k
 php-mbstring         x86_64         5.4.16-36.el7_1         base         503 k
 php-mysql            x86_64         5.4.16-36.el7_1         base          99 k
 php-pdo              x86_64         5.4.16-36.el7_1         base          97 k
 php-xml              x86_64         5.4.16-36.el7_1         base         124 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install  1 Package
Upgrade             ( 9 Dependent packages)

Total download size: 6.3 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
------
------
------

Installed:
  php-soap.x86_64 0:5.4.16-36.el7_1

Dependency Updated:
  php.x86_64 0:5.4.16-36.el7_1          php-cli.x86_64 0:5.4.16-36.el7_1
  php-common.x86_64 0:5.4.16-36.el7_1   php-devel.x86_64 0:5.4.16-36.el7_1
  php-gd.x86_64 0:5.4.16-36.el7_1       php-mbstring.x86_64 0:5.4.16-36.el7_1
  php-mysql.x86_64 0:5.4.16-36.el7_1    php-pdo.x86_64 0:5.4.16-36.el7_1
  php-xml.x86_64 0:5.4.16-36.el7_1

Complete!
```

2) yum search php-soap

```
============================ N/S matched: php-soap =============================
php-soap.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use the SOAP protocol
```

3) service httpd restart

To verify run following

4) php -m | grep -i soap

soap

Comment: after run this command `find -name soap.so` in root folder i see this is soap path `./usr/lib64/php/modules/soap.so` i set this line  `extension='./usr/lib64/php/modules/soap.so'` `/etc/php.ini` file and restart httpd services in cent os 6. but still it couldn't enable soap service. any idea?

Comment: I need a help.Will installing soap also upgrade other dependencies version ?? It is showing the same display as you described above.

Comment: @MunishChechi I don't think so, but may be for compatibility you might need to upgrade other dependencies.

Answer (score 5):

The `yum install php-soap` command will install the Soap module for php 5.x

For installing the correct version for your environment I recommend to create a file `info.php` and put this code: `<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>`

In the header you'll see the version you're using:

[image]

Now that you know the correct version you can run this command: `yum search php-soap`

This command will return the avaliable versions:

```
php-soap.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use the SOAP protocol
php54-php-soap.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use the SOAP protocol
php55-php-soap.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use the SOAP protocol
php56-php-soap.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use the SOAP protocol
php70-php-soap.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use the SOAP protocol
php71-php-soap.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use the SOAP protocol
php72-php-soap.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use the SOAP protocol
php73-php-soap.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use the SOAP protocol
php74-php-soap.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use the SOAP protocol
rh-php70-php-soap.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use the SOAP protocol
rh-php71-php-soap.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use the SOAP protocol
rh-php72-php-soap.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use the SOAP protocol
```

Now you just need to choose the correct module to your php version.

For this example, you should run this command `php72-php-soap.x86_64`

Answer (score 1):

After hours of searching I think my problem was that command `yum install php-soap`  installs the latest version of soap for the latest php version.

My php version was `7.027`, but latest php version is `7.2`   so I had to search for the right soap version and finaly found it [HERE!](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-sclo-rh/rh-php70-php-soap-7.0.10-2.el7.x86_64.rpm.html)

`yum install rh-php70-php-soap`

Now `php -m | grep -i soap` works, Output: `soap`

Do not forget to restart `httpd` service.