# Error: php55w-common conflicts with php-common on CentOS 6.5

Tags: php, soap, conflict, centos6

I have installed a fresh 64-bit CentOS 6.5 with PHP5, Mysql5.5, etc.

Now when I want to install different apache modules, like php-soap, I get this error:

```
---> Package php-soap.x86_64 0:5.3.3-27.el6_5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-27.el6_5 for package: php-soap-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.3.3-27.el6_5 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: php55w-common-5.5.12-1.w6.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 5.5.0
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php55w-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I use this command to install php-soap:

> yum --enablerepo=webtatic install php-soap

Answer (score 16):

I just found the solution to my issue!

use the following command to install php-soap:

```
yum install php55w-soap
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was installing the XML module, not SOAP but changing the command to `yum install php55w-xml` worked a treat. Thanks for this!

Comment: For me -- `sudo yum install php55-soap` (removing the `w`, and be sure to run as `sudo` (root)

Comment: I am running centos 6.8 PHP 7 in January 2017 and this worked for me: yum install php70w-soap from https://webtatic.com/packages/php70/

Comment: Great, Thanks. 
Work for me installing php-mbstring with php55w-mbstring
      
Checking if it was installing doing: php -m |grep mbstring
Checking if it was loaded with: php -r 'php -r 'echo extension_loaded("mbstring") ? 1 : 2; '

Restarting httpd service

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have installed postfix and dovecot on my Centos. I am using Interspire Email marketer (IEM) which needs php-imap module. I installed squirrelmail and can send out mails as well as receive mails using squirrelmail interface. But using IEM I always get error that imap module is not installed so I tried the following and got the errors below. I am totally confused what I should do. I thought if squirrelmail can read mails, IEM should also be able to read. If I must install php-imap again, what to do with  all the errors below.

```
yum install php-imap 
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/metalink                                                                                                                                                           | 4.4 kB     00:00     
 * base: centos.webwerks.com
 * epel: mirror.premi.st
 * extras: centos.webwerks.com
 * updates: centos.webwerks.com
 * webtatic: sp.repo.webtatic.com
base                                                                                                                                                                    | 3.7 kB     00:00     
extras                                                                                                                                                                  | 3.4 kB     00:00     
updates                                                                                                                                                                 | 3.4 kB     00:00     
webtatic                                                                                                                                                                | 3.6 kB     00:00     
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-imap.x86_64 0:5.3.3-48.el6_8 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-48.el6_8 for package: php-imap-5.3.3-48.el6_8.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.3.3-48.el6_8 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: php55w-common-5.5.38-1.w6.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 5.5
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php55w-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.3-48.el6_8.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following command to solve the same issue:

`yum remove php*
yum install php55w-soap`

Answer (score 0):

yum -y install php55w php55w-fpm php55w-soap php55w-opcache php55w-xml php55w-mcrypt php55w-gd php55w-devel php55w-mysql php55w-intl php55w-mbstring php55w-bcmath