# Can' get PHP SOAP enabled

Tags: php, soap, php-extension

I think I have installed SOAP using:

```
yum install php-soap
```

However, when I use the following command:

```
 php -i | grep -i soap
```

I get this error message:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Start-up: Unable to load dynamic library
```

`'/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/php_soap.dll'` `- /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/php_soap.dll`: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

When I try to install SOAP again, it says it's installed already. In my `php.ini` file I have uncommitted the line:

```
extension=php_soap.dll
```

What am I still missing?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Found my .so file with: "find / -name soap.so" (at root)

Then placed that path in my php.ini file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check this answer you might find your clue

[how-to-enable-soap-on-centos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22594582/how-to-enable-soap-on-centos)

You should point to some soap.so library. DLLs are usually on windows. Check your libraries path */usr/local/lib/php/extensions* and see if any soap.so library is to be found there

Comment: Found it, thanks! I've edited my question for anyone who wants to know how.